# Adwords conversion tracking on link clicks that open in a new tab

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to track the conversion for links in adwords; For this i have the classic code that looks like this(don't worry about values for conversion_id and conversion_label):

```
<!-- Google Code for Joc Sloturi2 Conversion Page
In your html page, add the snippet and call
goog_report_conversion when someone clicks on the
chosen link or button. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 /* <![CDATA[ */
 goog_snippet_vars = function() {
var w = window;
w.google_conversion_id = xxxxxxx;
w.google_conversion_label = "dsadsadsadsadadsa";
w.google_conversion_value = dsadasda;
w.google_conversion_currency = "RON";
w.google_remarketing_only = false;
}
// DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
goog_snippet_vars();
window.google_conversion_format = "3";
var opt = new Object();
opt.onload_callback = function() {
if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
  window.location = url;
  window.open(url, '_blank')
}
}
var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
conv_handler(opt);
}
}
 /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

After that the outbound links are looking like this

```
<a href="linkURL" onclick="goog_report_conversion('linkURL')" target="_blank">Link text whatever</a>
```

My problem with this is that when I click on the link it opens the link in a new tab and also in the same tab (basically it opens the link twice); Is there a way to only open the link in a new tab in the browser and also track the conversion for it?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but I found a solution. Remove

```
window.location = url;
```